# use gsub in R to cut the character out between two slashes

Tags: regex, r

I have a file name captured by R like the following:

```
"0097_abcdef/0097_0/0097_0_04_bed.dbf"
```

I need to pick up the term between the two slashes `/` (i.e. `0097_0`), but I have tried `gsub(".*/","",dbf.files[1])`, but it gives me `"0097_0_04_bed.dbf"`, which is not quite what I want.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try using -

```
 .*/(.*)/.*
```

and use the first group e.g. \1

```
> x = "0097_abcdef/0097_0/0097_0_04_bed.dbf"
> sub(".*/(.*)/.*","\\1",x)
[1] "0097_0"
```

Answer (score 6):

A different approach is to use the file path manipulation functions. I my opinion, it is a bit clearer than a regexpr - and it handles Windows paths correctly as well:

```
# On a Linux path
x <- "0097_abcdef/0097_0/0097_0_04_bed.dbf"
basename( dirname(x) )
# [1] "0097_0"

# On a Windows path
y <- "c:\\0097_abcdef\\0097_0\\0097_0_04_bed.dbf"
basename( dirname(y) )
# [1] "0097_0"
```

..They are vectorized so you can give them a vector of paths.
For completeness, there is also `file.path` to stitch the parts together again.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `strsplit` instead. For example,

```
R> x = "0097_abcdef/0097_0/0097_0_04_bed.dbf"
R> strsplit(x, "/")
[[1]]
[1] "0097_abcdef"       "0097_0"            "0097_0_04_bed.dbf"

R> strsplit(x, "/")[[1]][2]
[1] "0097_0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use read.table:

```
tc <- textConnection(dbf.files)
y <- read.table(tc,sep="/",as.is=TRUE)[2]
close(tc)
```